# Neo4j fails to rollback test data with 2-leg relationships

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Figured out the following issue with testing Neo4j nodes & relationships persistence via Spring Data. When I setup 2-leg rels, like `A -> B -> C` and then try to persist all three entities with saving them one by one, everything goes fine until SDN4J starts transaction rollback after test execution.

As I found in debug logs, persisting both nodes and rels goes fine, but when it starts rolling back, it fails on removing rels with the exception:

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher "Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound"; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound; Description: Relationship with id 1124
at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.response.AbstractHttpResponse.initialise(AbstractHttpResponse.java:83) ~[neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.response.AbstractHttpResponse.<init>(AbstractHttpResponse.java:74) ~[neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.response.RowModelResponse.<init>(RowModelResponse.java:31) ~[neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:123) ~[neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor.executeSave(RequestExecutor.java:107) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:75) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:44) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:425) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:203) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
...
```

A simple code sample to show exactly what I'm trying to do:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class Neo4jRelsPersistenceTest {

    @Autowired
    EntityDao entityDao;

    @Test
    public void testTwoLegRelationship() throws Exception {
        Entity e1 = new Entity();
        Entity e2 = new Entity();
        Entity e3 = new Entity();

        AssociateRelationship rel1 = new AssociateRelationship();
        rel1.setEntityFrom(e1);
        rel1.setEntityTo(e2);
        e1.setAssociateOf(new HashSet() {{add(rel1);}});

        AssociateRelationship rel2 = new AssociateRelationship();
        rel2.setEntityFrom(e3);
        rel2.setEntityTo(e1); // if change to 'setEntityTo(e2)', it will work
        e3.setAssociateOf(new HashSet() {{add(rel2);}});

        entityDao.saveEntities(Arrays.asList(e1, e2, e3));
    }
}
```

Can you please suggest where to look for the resolution / some W/A, or point on a problem in the code?

Jut let me know if any additional info would make sense here

**Update:**

Issue was reproduced with Bolt driver as well. I will create a project-independent case to check whether the issue will have place or not

Comment: Would like to investigate further, are you able to send a sample? jasper@graphaware.com

Comment: @JasperBlues I've put a mail on this address, please let me know which data you need to make you able to reproduce and investigate this